# Well-posedness of Euler-Poisson system for semiconductors

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Is there anyone can recommend me some important literature references about the well-posedness of both Cauchy problem and initial boundary value problem of Euler-Poisson system for semiconductors? Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter Markowich has worked extensively on this type of problem. Just look up his publications on Math Reviews.

Comment: @Michael Renardy:Thank you very much!